# DDD: Aggregate Root references child Entity that belongs to another Aggregate root

Tags: domain-driven-design

Here is the problem I am trying to solve. I have CLIENT. That CLIENT needs software to manage **INCIDENTS**.

The **CLIENT** has multiple **FACILITIES**. Each **FACILITY** contains multiple **LOCATIONS**.

When they log an **INCIDENT**, the minimum info they need to log is the **LOCATION** where it happened, the **FACILITY** for **LOCATION** where it happened and WHAT happened.

So I have questions are modelling this problem. This is what I have.

[image]

Here is my question:
I this a good design. The **FACILITY** root makes sense imo, because a **LOCATION** cannot exist on its own. But Incident now holds a soft reference to both **FACILITY** and **LOCATION**.

I considered making **LOCATION** a value object instead of entity. I this case **INCIDENT** would have its own copy of **LOCATION**. But this becomes a problem if **LOCATION** mutates.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Maybe I am missing something. Just for the record - **INCIDENTS** as they contains workflow etc become very complicated and is the core domain. Maybe only **INCIDENT** should be solved with DDD?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if the location changes are you sure you want the changes to propagate to the incident's location as well? I guess the only reason for it to change would be fixing typos, but that's a question you need to ask.

In any case, you can reference the composite ID, which I would most represent as an `IncidentLocation` value object. The rule only states that you can't have an object reference to the child entity and that you can't only reference the child entity's ID given it's only guaranteed to be unique within it's root.

Please note that it may be a good idea to have at least two contexts here. A CRUD-based context where facilities and such details would be managed and an incident logging context where the incident's lifecycle could be managed. In that case `Location` could be an entity in the first context and an immutable value object `Location {facilityId, locationId}` in the second context.

Comment: @MegaByte: *How* the location is going to be mutated is an important question.  Consider an `Order` with a `LineItem` that references a `ProductId` where the customer ordered 5 "Red Pens".  However, someone discovers that the pens are actually *blue* and changes the description to "Blue Pens".  That quite drastically changes the order.  It would lead to quite a bit of confusion.  The same would happen with your location changing.  A typo is going to be OK but some significant changes may take place that may result in the `Incident` being affected in some adverse way.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I like the IncidentLocation value object/composite id approach. In my case the locationId is a guid under the hood, so it should be unique. Is it still a good idea/practice to include the facilityId as part of the composite key?

Comment: @MegaByte Well, it doesn't make much sense to have a globally unique identifier for a nested entity in the first place. It seems rather inefficient? The danger of not adding facilityId is that your model becomes dependent on the guarantee that the sub-entity ID will always be unique while this is not a limitation of the common DDD modeling rules. If you ever have to lookup the children entity from your domain it will also feel much less natural (e.g. findFacilityByLocation(locationId)).